# Is there a way to add custom fields to the document in a template from the API which can be further used through DocuSign console?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am working on integrating DocuSign by using DocuSign C# client. So far I could use TemplatesApi to create a template with a document. Now, I want some custom fields added to the document in the template so that the user can place these custom fields on the document in the template through the DocuSign console. I have tried adding the document custom fields and tabs for particular signer but it doesn't work.

Further, I would need to create envelopes based on the template and populate the custom fields/tabs with unique values (like name, job title etc) for each envelope.

Instead of custom fields if there is some other functionality that helps me achieve this then that would work too.

Comment: who is the user that will place the custom fields? is that the signer or the sender?

Comment: The user would be the sender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this method:

```
 CustomFields CreateCustomFields (string accountId, string templateId, TemplateCustomFields templateCustomFields = null);
```

in the TemplatesApi
you will have to provide the accountId, templateId and the (one or more) custom fields you wish to add to the template.

Comment: This is not what I want. I want to set the custom fields in the template's document. Once this is set, it will be used to create envelopes. And then I want to populate unique values for every envelope. TemplatesApi has a CreateCustomFields method but that does not help either since it is for the template and not the template's document.

Comment: oh, ok, it wasn't clear. let me add another answer on how to add custom fields to a template

Comment: I'll modify my answer, it's very similar

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case, the custom field gets added to the template but I still cannot access it to place it on the template's document. I have set the 'show' property to 'true' for the custom field. Maybe I am speaking some wrong terminology. My requirement is to create a custom field in the template so that the sender can place it on the document where needed. Later, when we need to send for signing, create an envelope using this template and put a unique value in the previously created custom field.

Comment: The admin panel has 'Document Custom Fields'. Would you know how to create these through the API. I couldn't find any method for this.

Comment: aha, you want it placed later. Then it has to be account-wide. Template custom fields do not work like that. When you want is an account-wide custom field and then senders can add it to any envelope regardless of the template that was selected. does that help?

Comment: That sounds about right. Could you tell me how to achieve this through the API?

Comment: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Accounts/AccountCustomFields/create

Comment: using C# SDK, use this:
 CustomFields CreateCustomField (string accountId, CustomField customField = null, AccountsApi.CreateCustomFieldOptions options = null);
in AccountsApi

Comment: I have tried this but doesn't work with my use case. If there are thousands of documents to be sent out then the sender has to place the fields for every document. Moreover, the created custom field shows in the Admin section but not for templates/envelopes.

Comment: well, I'm not sure then. We may want to start from scratch and understand your use case. It may be that there's a better way to have this. I understand you want your end-user to place them

Comment: you want to have a template that includes one ore more document and you want your senders to be able to add fields? is that the requirement? I'm just trying to understand the "custom" part

Comment: First of all, thanks for your quick replies. Appreciate it. Let me try explaining in steps: 1. Create template in my app (through DocuSign API) with document and some custom fields for that template. 2. Navigate the user to DocuSign to place these fields on the doc. 3. Save and close the template. 4. Later, when the doc needs to be sent for signing, create the envelope from my app (API) based on the template and now put unique values in the custom fields which were added in the template earlier. 5. Preview the doc on DocuSign. 6. Send the doc. 7. Keep repeating steps 4 to 6 as needed.

Comment: aha, so you don't really need custom fields

Comment: what you need is to do embedded sending, where you actually go to edit a template embedded in your app and start on the tagging screen

Comment: this is very similar to doing embedded sending

Comment: look at the code here - https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/blob/master/eg-03-csharp-auth-code-grant-core/Controllers/Eg011EmbeddedSendingController.cs

Comment: try to get this working first with an envelope. changing to a template is very simple, but want you to understand how this works conceptually first

Comment: Thanks Inbar. I do need custom fields. A little more about them - There are some values from my app which will need to be placed on the document. I would need the sender to place only specific fields on the document. I will also be using the embedded sending as in the code example you mentioned. And for templates I will be using the embedded CreateEdit view too.

Comment: ok, there are about 5 or 6 things you want to do. Which ones of them do you know how to do using the API and which you do not know?

Comment: ... and that would be related to custom fields. 1. How do I pass them to DocuSign so that they appear in the template document view of DS and the sender can place them on the document. 2. When creating envelopes, how are these fields (which are already in the template doc) populated with particular values?

Comment: they have to be on the account for this (#1) they cannot be passed just to be used for a specific template.

Comment: Q #2 - depends, how do you want them to? you can do that via the API or you can have the end-end-user (the signer) fill them. your choice

Comment: Both will be done via the API. Can't get that to work though. How to achieve this via the API has been my question all along.

Comment: CustomFields CreateCustomField (string accountId, CustomField customField = null, AccountsApi.CreateCustomFieldOptions options = null);
in AccountsApi to do #1.

Comment: These fields get created in Envelope Custom Fields. They don't show when creating the template and adding fields in the document. The fields that would show are Document Custom Fields. Does not seem like there is a way to add these through the API. Is that right?

Comment: For this you can't use SDK, but there's an API like this: 
POST https://{{hostenv}}/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/tab_definitions
body:
{
  “font”: “couriernew”,
  “bold”: false,
  “italic”: false,
  “underline”: false,
  “fontColor”: “brightred”,
  “fontSize”: “size12”,
  “anchor”: “”,
  “width”: 30,
  “initialvalue”: “jnokdESXHSkPOIz”,
  “locked”: false,
  “name”: “CWcpCfLDTYorSsELMfYX”,
  “required”: false,
  “shared”: false,
  “tabLabel”: “NVlDbaffTCboxGS”,
  “type”: “signerattachment”,
  “selected”: “”
}

Comment: Thanks, will try this out

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted for #1. Could get #2 working too. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Happy to help, #2 is actually simple, as it doesn't matter that it's "custom" these are just tabs and you have to fill the values using the API for a specific envelope. Let me know if you need me to show you how to do this with the C# SDK